# Trouble copying table to Excel based on criteria

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, vba

I'm getting an error saying *Run-time error '424': Object required* when trying to run:

```
Function CreateDailyReadOnlyCVG()

Dim sql, strStatusReport, strDailyCVG, strOutputFileName As String

strOutputFileName = "mit-msp01\cs\CUS Supply Chain\All Division Reporting\Field Retrievals\Status Reports\CVG" & _
Format(Date, "yyyyMMdd") & ".xlsx"

    If tRetrieval.[Retrieval_Status] = "A" And tRetrieval.[BU] = "CVG" Then _
      sql = "INSERT * FROM tRetrieval_Status_Report_CVG INSERT INTO tDaily_Report_CVG"
      DoCmd.RunSQL sql
      DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "Daily Report", " & strOutputFileName & ", True
      SetAttr " & strOutputFileName & ", vbReadOnly

End Function
```

It compiles fine, but then I run it and get the error. Also, I feel like this won't run anyway.

Comment: Which line in the code causes the error?

Comment: Your SQL statement is a (badly formulated) INSERT. It should be a SELECT.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
Sub CreateDailyReadOnlyCVG()

Dim sql, strOutputFileName As String
Dim intCounter As Integer

strOutputFileName = "J:\CUS Supply Chain\All Division Reporting\Field Retrievals\Status Reports\CVG\Retrieval Status Report CVG" & _
Format(Date, "yyyyMMdd") & ".xls"


sql = "INSERT INTO tDaily_Report_CVG SELECT * FROM tRetrieval_Status_Report_CVG;"

intCounter = DCount("[Retrieval_ID]", "tRetrieval", "[BU] = 'CVG' AND [Retrieval_Status] = 'A'")

    If intCounter > 0 Then
        DoCmd.RunSQL sql
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "tDaily_Report_CVG", _
        " & strOutputFileName & ", True
        SetAttr " & strOutputFileName & ", vbReadOnly
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: 1. `Dim sql AS STRING, strOutputFileName As String`. 2. Do you really want only `DoCmd.RunSQL sql` in the If clause? If yes, correct your indentation. If not, drop the _ after Then, and add an `End If` at the end of the block. 3. You are mixing xls and xlsx. Better: use `strOutputFileName`.

Comment: Thanks. Just how it copied in and I thought I got all the .xlsx's changed. I do want it in the if clause, yeah. It's dependent on the if and only will run if the criteria are met.